# Storing Models in CKRecord

Tags: ios, swift, database, model, cloudkit

My model is an array of colors.

```
var colors = [Color]() {didSet{tableView.reloadData()}}
```

I define a color as the following:

```
class Color{

    var title: String
    var color: UIColor
    var selected: Bool = false

    init(title: String, color: UIColor) {
        self.title = title
        self.color = color
    }
}
```

I want to be able to store my array of colors in a single CKRecord. I'm aware that a CKRecord's fields can only be of certain types so I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

Comment: Sridhar, `its attributes in a a single CKRecord.` means what? you should explain detail .

Comment: @aircraft I edited my question. Hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: do you mean the custom class Instance store fail ? or you do not know how to store the custom class Instance ?